# MergeSort not working

Tags: java, mergesort

im trying to implement mergesort but i am not sure what the error is. im sure my logic is fine but i am messing up the indexes. Would really appreciate some feedback:

```
public static void mergeSort(long[] arr, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {

        int mid = (high + low) / 2;
        mergeSort(arr, low, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid+1, high);
        merge(arr, low, mid, high);
    }
}

public static void merge(long[] arr, int low, int mid, int high) {
    long[] tmp = new long[arr.length];
    //System.out.println((high-low+1)==arr.length);
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, tmp, 0, arr.length);
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = 0;
    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (tmp[i] <= tmp[j]) {
            arr[k] = tmp[i];
            i++;
        } else {
            arr[k] = tmp[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }


    while (i <= mid) {

        arr[k] = tmp[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j <= high) {

        arr[k] = tmp[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you write what error are you getting? And what the line they accure?

Comment: its not an error. my output is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the worng answear before, didn't looked much.

Now i found you bug, and tested it to be sure.

Here he is

```
int k = 0;
```

It should be

```
int k = i;
```